# how to open the file that was downloaded by wget

Tags: linux, wget

I got a large set of directories and files to download (~700G). The provider of the data instructed in the email:

> The recommended way (if available to you) is to use the following
> commands from a Bash shell to get and run a script that downloads all
> of the files in the above mentioned directory:
>
> ```
> wget --no-check-certificate -O wget_commands https://url/download
> bash wget_commands
> ```
>
> If a download with this 'wget_commands' script is interrupted, you can
> resume the download by rerunning it, thus:
>
> ```
> bash wget_commands
> ```

However, when I downloaded it, I got a file instead of directory. I understand I gave an output name as `wget_commands`

When I try `bash wget_commands` it gives me the following error

```
wget_commands: wget_commands: cannot execute binary file
```

I tried to give the output a `foo.gz` name and then `gunzip` it, but it was not accepting it as a `gzip` folder.

How do I access the downloaded data?

Comment: What does `file wget_commands` return

Comment: Did execution of `bash wget_commands` produce any additional output? As it reads to me, `wget_commands` is a bash script that manages the actual download. You can check that easily by looking at the contents of `wget_commands` using `cat` or any text editor.

Comment: I'd also be leery of a site that advertises a https connection but cannot maintain their certificates, thus requiring `--no-check-certificate`.  Always check your download before executing the file.

Comment: @roaima it gives "wget_commands: Zip archive data, at least v3.0 to extract"

Comment: Then the instructions you were given by your supplier are wrong and I suggest you go back to them for correct instructions

Comment: @Simon that's what I thought. But "cat wget_commands" gives a binary file output. 'bash wget_commands' gives only  'wget_commands: wget_commands: cannot execute binary file'. Also, when I list the files in the directory, wget_commands size is ~700G

Comment: @roaima yeah, he quit recently. Nobody in that department knows how it works. I wonder if it is a zip archive data, maybe I should put -O foo.zip then instead of foo.gz?

Comment: Linux tools don't usually care much about file extensions, it's more about file contents. Have you just tried `unzip` instead of `gunzip`?

Comment: @Simon, yes, unzip worked. I tried to gunzip several times, but then found out it was a zip archive. If you post this as an answer, I will accept it. Thank you